# Why did mechanical units explode when being fixed by SCVs in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I had a bunch of mechanical units what I was using to attack an enemy, since they took some damage I sent some SCVs and started fixing them. Instead of getting fixed, they got destroyed. Any ideas why? and how do you fix mechanical units?

Comment: Did you attack / attack move instead of right click on them? The animation for repair is similar to the animation to attack as an SCV.

Comment: @walrushelmet maybe I did, I'm just getting started. Should this have worked? repairing that way I mean.

Comment: Like walrus helmet said, you most likely attacked them @J.PabloFernández yes it should have worked!

Answer (score 4):

To repair a mechanical unit with an SCV, right click on the unit with the SCV selected, or select 'Repair' from the menu on the bottom right. You can also press 'R' then click on the unit you want to repair.

If you accidentally press 'A' then click on a friendly unit, your SCV will start attacking the unit and dealing damage, causing them to explode when they run out of HP.

[image]

Comment: Also note that right clicking on repair or ALT + R will set repair to autocast.  This has the benefit of allowing you to attack-move SCVs with the rest of your units, and they'll prioritize repairing units closeby, rather than attacking enemy units.